# Why is the Power at the receiving antenna (as per Friis transmission equation) proportional to wavelength squared?

Tags: energy, power

Power at the receiving antenna is given by the Friis transmission formula, which says that the received power is proportional to the wavelength squared. But energy carried by an electromagnetic wave E=hc/lambda which is inversely proportional to the wavelength. Shouldn't they both have the same relationship with wavelength?

Answer (score 1):

The energy $E=hc/\lambda$ is the energy of a *single* [photon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon).
But the receiving power of an antenna is related to the
energy of *many* photons. Therefore these two quantities
are not comparable without knowing the number of photons.

Answer (score 0):

$E=hc/\lambda$ is the energy carried by one photon but for power you need to compute,

energy carried by one photon $\times$ number of photons per second.